# Updating polymer 2 array of objects shows duplicate values?

Tags: arrays, polymer-2.x

I'm trying to update a paper-dropdown-menu. After the first time updating, I see the options array correctly shows the new item appended the array.

The issue happens for any subsequent additions to that array, the new value is seen for all previous items I've added.

Any ideas why this is happening and how to resolve?

tried:

```
this.options.push(myNewOption);

this.push('options', myNewOption);
```

EXPECTED:

1st time adding:

```
this.options
0: {'john', 'smith'}
1: {'one', 'one'}
```

This is fine.

2nd time adding:

```
this.options
0: {'john', 'smith'}
1: {'one', 'one'}
2: {'two', 'two'}
```

index 1 now shows the name from the 2nd add!

3rd time adding:

```
this.options
0: {'john', 'smith'}
1: {'one', 'one'}
2: {'two', 'two'}
3: {'three', 'three'}
```

ACTUAL:

For example: 
1st time adding:

```
this.options
0: {'john', 'smith'}
1: {'one', 'one'}
```

This is fine.

2nd time adding:

```
this.options
0: {'john', 'smith'}
1: {'two', 'two'}
2: {'two', 'two'}
```

index 1 now shows the name from the 2nd add!

3rd time adding:

```
this.options
0: {'john', 'smith'}
1: {'three', 'three'}
2: {'three', 'three'}
3: {'three', 'three'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `this.push` or `this.set` to change properties of your polymer component so polymer knows when to rerender stuff. So using

```
this.push('options', myNewOption);
```

is the right approach. See the [Documentation](https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/model-data) for this.

Comment: hmm I had tried this.push('options', myNewOption) but still saw the same issue. I'm reading somewhere it might have to do with objects inside where the objects are being passed by reference and to do something like myObj = {} first. Not sure about the exact syntax yet, but will give that a shot

Comment: It doesn't seem like an issue with the rerendering. it looks like an issue with the new object overwriting previously added array elements.